# WebRequest and WebMethods interop

Tags: .net, winforms, webrequest, webmethod

VS2010, C#, .NET 4

I created 2 applications : A web service and a Windows forms application(both running on the same PC). Here is the code :

WEBSERVICE :

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "message";
    }
}
```

WINDOWS APPLICATION:

```
HttpWebRequest req =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:20848/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld");

req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
req.Method = "POST";                
//Set the content type of the data being posted.
req.ContentType = "application/text";

WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
string txtOutput = sr.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

THIS WORKS JUST FINE. I get the response from the webservice which contains message. 
Now I alter the application 2 applications to this :

WEB SERVICE :

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld(string message)
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

WINDOWS FORMS APPLICATION :

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:20848/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld");

req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
req.Method = "POST";
string inputData = "sample webservice";
string postData = "message=" + inputData;

byte[] byte1 = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
req.ContentLength = byte1.Length;
Stream postdataStream = req.GetRequestStream();

//Set the content type of the data being posted.
req.ContentType = "application/text";

postdataStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);

WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
string txtOutput = sr.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

THIS FAILS AT THE req.GetResponse(); "It says that the underlying connection has closed" . Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code here. Note - I MUST access the WebMethods with WebRequests only. I do not want to Add Web reference.

Comment: What in the world are you doing? Why would you not use "Add Service Reference"? You shouldn't be using ASMX services and "Add Web Reference" for new development.

Comment: Is your service set up to do SOAP, or "HttpPost"?

Comment: If you explain why you can't add a web service reference maybe someone will be able to better help you. That makes little sense from a practical standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you don't close the request stream before you call GetResponse(). I haven't tested it, but the example in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx) closes the request stream. Either way it's good practice, so try that first.

I.e.

```
postdataStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
postDataStream.Close();
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: OK. Break out a packet sniffer (Fiddler, Wireshark, etc.). Does the request actually get sent? As in, is it the server closing the connection? Or is the framework not even sending it? Other things to try... application/text... it's just plain text. Shouldn't it be text/plain? And I notice you're using ASCII encoding. I don't have the http spec to hand, but I would give UTF8 a crack.